# fuzzifier() in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I have written this following piece of code to fuzzify all the IRIS data set attributes into three labels(narrow, medium, wide).

```
varinp.mf <- matrix(c(1,1,1,4,5,6,5,6,7,6,7,8), nrow = 4,
           ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)  
test = read.csv("iris.data.txt")  
View(test)  
test1 = test[1:4]  
View(test1)  
fuzzifier(test1, num.varinput = 4, num.labels.input = 3, varinp.mf)
```

> Error in num.labels.input[1, i] : incorrect number of dimensions

The varinp.mf takes a 4*3 matrix as an input. I am using the triangular membership function for each of the three labels. The IRIS data set is first read into an object test and from that, I have read the first four columns (sepal length,width and petal length,width) into another object test1. Now when I use the fuzzifier function, this error message is displayed on the console.
Can anyone please explain it?

Comment: The matrix `varinp.mf` must have five rows, see "Details" in `?frbs::fuzzifier`

Comment: so even though the triangle function only takes 3 parameters (a,b,c), I have to include a row for the parameter 'd'?

Comment: I have never used the package and I don't know how to apply it. Sorry; this is why I posted my remark as a comment. Hopefully others can provide a detailed answer. The [reference manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/frbs/) states that the matrix must be a (5,n) matrix.

Comment: did that, still shows the same error. But thanks @RHertel